# How to get username instead of userid in audit log in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to audit a Linux system (Ubuntu 16) for which I have installed `auditd`, I am getting the logs and have used `ausearch` and `aureport` to parse the information.

However the problem is I need to send those logs to our server. We have 100s of system with multiple usernames the log send `user_id` instead of `user_name` which can create lot of problems so how do I get `user_name` instead of `user_id`?

Here are some example log details:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1554812307.306:589): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=55868e8a7000 a1=7fffe83fdc10 a2=1 a3=ffffffff items=2 ppid=2170 pid=2854 auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 euid=1001 suid=1001 fsuid=1001 egid=1001 sgid=1001 fsgid=1001 tty=pts20 ses=4294967295 comm="vi" exe="/usr/bin/vim.basic" key="delete"

type=CWD msg=audit(1554812307.306:589): cwd="/home/mayank"

type=PATH msg=audit(1554812307.306:589): item=0 name="/home/mayank" inode=919539 dev=08:03 mode=040755 ouid=1001 ogid=1001 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT

type=PATH msg=audit(1554812307.306:589): item=1 name=".potato.txt.swx" inode=919552 dev=08:03 mode=0100600 ouid=1001 ogid=1001 rdev=00:00 nametype=DELETE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` replace `log_format = RAW` with `log_format = ENRICHED`, and restart auditd.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the work around for this.

```
Use: ausearch - i
```

This will interpret numeric entities to text and if you want to save it in log you can redirect the output

```
ausearch -i > my_log.txt
```

The above will convert many numeric data like epoch time into regular as well so its very helpful.